# Excel VBA: Check all check boxes on Web Page

Tags: excel, vba, web

I'm trying to check all the checkboxes available on a webpage via VBA since the name convention doesnt appear to be one in which I can be selective.  However I cannot seem to get anything to work. I can login to the website and navigate to the section of the website I want but cannot cross this hurdle.  Any help would be greatly appreciate.  Below is the source code from the webpage.

```
       <li data-product-family="30yr"
            data-product-amortizationTerm="30"
            data-product-type="Conventional"
            data-product-amortizationType="Fixed"

        >
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
            value="154232" 
            class="product-Conventional product-item" 
            data-authorized-remittance-types="ActualActual "
            />30-Year Fixed Rate - 110k Max Loan Amount</label>
        </li>
```

VBA I attempted to write (edited)... code I'm using presently:

```
Public Sub TestIE()
Dim IE As Object
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long


' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = False

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "https://"

' Statusbar
Application.StatusBar = "Page is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.Visible = True

Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
If aNodeList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length
aNodeList.Item(i).Checked = True
Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Exit For` instructs the loop to exit upon the very first match.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'm somewhat new to this.  I would expect that if that was the only issue it would at least check the first checkbox, which it doesnt appear to do.  I get an automation error and unspecified error when running the code.

Comment: `I cannot seem to get anything to work` or `but cannot cross this hurdle`: these statements don't give us a lot to work on. Are you getting an error message? what happens when you run the code? Plus, don't use a `Click`, you should be able to use `.Checked` property to set the checkbox.. unless you are working with embedded elements?

Comment: See errors above.  I tried changing to 'checked' from 'Click' to no avail.

Exact error reads:
    Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
    Automation error
    Unspecified error

Comment: Just to clarify, to set the element as checked, you would set it as: `objElement(i).Checked = True`

Comment: Also, see what @QHarr has done. Use the `.Length` property to get the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get a nodeList of the checkboxes with:

```
IE.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
```

You can traverse the nodeList along its .Length property.

E.g.

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
If aNodeList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length -1
    On Error Resume Next
    aNodeList.item(i).Checked  = True
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

Comment: QHarr, that works great. That said, it did create a new error: Run time error 424 Object Required.  Any thoughts?  Not sure if its trying to continuous loop?  I updated the original post with the code I'm now using.

Comment: I suspect you might have to set for condition as: `For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1` maybe?

Comment: Damn did I miss that. Sorry. Thanks zac! Ye, it is zero based so you go to length -1. You can also “mask” with an on error resume next and it is worth checking whether checking a box executes any JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Only reason I suggested that was because I've done it millions of times myself :)